# ES2015 modules, should I import / export everything?

Tags: javascript, class, import, ecmascript-6, export

I started using **import** and **export** in javascript recently, but I am a bit confused. I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to export, and what I'm supposed to keep local to the file. I don't know how to express this nice in english, so here is a small section from my code:

The */client/js/Inventory.js* file, module:

```
import {
  $,
  renderHTML,
  game
} from "../main.js";

const template = {
  titanium: {
    name: "Titanium",
    description: "Description here..."
  }
}

export default class Inventory {
  constructor(inventory) {
    this._name = inventory.name;
    this._description = inventory.description;
  }

  get name() {return this._name}
  get description() {return this._description}

  generate(id) {
    renderHTML("inventory, `
      <div class="inventory" id="${id}">
        content here...
      </div>
    `);
  }

  static make(id) {
    game.inventory[id] = new Inventory(template[id]);
    game.inventory[id].generate(id);
}
```

and my */client/main.js* file looks something like this:

```
import Inventory from "./js/Inventory.js";

const $ = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
const renderHTML = (id, str) => $(id).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);

const game = {
  inventory: {}
};

Inventory.make("titanium");

export {
  $,
  renderHTML,
  game
};
```

Since I'm exporting `game` object from the **main.js** file, does that mean a new `game` object is being created in the **Inventory.js** file after it's imported, or does that mean that the **Inventory.js** file can now access **main.js** file's `game` object?

Since I'm calling the classes inside the **main.js** file, do I also need to export the `template` object from the **Inventory.js** file, and import it inside the **main.js** file?

Exporting only the class works just fine, but I don't get how is the **main.js** accessing the template if it's not exported? Does it look in the **Inventory.js** file if none was found in the **main.js** or?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  Modules are a structured way of sharing code or data between different pieces of code.

You **export** any functions or data that you wish to share with other modules that will load your module.

If you have no intention of sharing it or no need to share it, don't export it.  If you do need to share it or some other module needs to be able to access it, you export it.  Export is the means of sharing with other other modules.

You **import** any properties from other modules that you need to use in this module.

For imports, you only import what you need now.  No need to import something you "might" need in the future.  You can always just add the import at the time you actually need it.

For exports, you only export what you specifically intend to share now.  If you find a need to share more later, you can always add another export later.

---

Code that is only used within this module does not need to be exported.  In fact, one of the benefits of modules is that you can maintain code privacy or protection in a module because other code cannot access anything in a module that is not exported or shared somehow via an export.

---

You can logically think of exports as the "api" for your module.  This is what other modules can call in your module.

You can logically think of imports as you specifying what "apis" you want to use from other modules.

When everything is in the global namespace (as with the original browser design), then there was no explicit export or import.  Everything declared at the top level was just public and shared.  This caused all sorts of problems, particularly as projects got larger and there got to be more and more files and then got even more complicated when you started trying to use third party code.

The module system is a structured way of saying that, by default, everything is private.  You then explicitly export only the things you want to share.  And, then when someone wants to use your apis, they explicitly import the apis they want to use.  Each module lives in it's own scope so has its own namespace.  Modules also make a very natural testable unit.

Before the standarization of Javascript modules, developers had build a whole bunch of different conventions to try to work-around the large flat global namespace in Javascript.  It was not uncommon to encounter multiple conventions in the same project if you were using 3rd party libraries.  For developers not trying to use a convention to solve this, code could get pretty messy with lots of potential for variable naming conflicts, accidental replacement of functions and a generally undocumented web of dependencies between files, etc...  The standardized module design attempts to provide one common way of addressing these issues and, in the process, also make it a lot easier to write reusable, testable, shareable code.

---

> Since I'm exporting game object from the main.js file, does that mean a new game object is being created in the Inventory.js file after it's imported, or does that mean that the Inventory.js file can now access main.js file's game object?

It means that Inventory.js can now export the one `game` object that was created in `main.js`.  There is no implicit copying when you export or import.

> Since I'm calling the classes inside the main.js file, do I also need to export the template object from the Inventory.js file, and import it inside the main.js file?

You only need to export things from `inventory.js` that you directly need to reference from some other file.  Since `main.js` does not need to reference the `template` variable directory, there is no need to export it.  The act of importing from `inventory.js` loads and runs that module.  That makes the `template` variable available to all the code inside `inventory.js` which is all your code needs.  So, no need to export it.

> Exporting only the class works just fine, but I don't get how is the main.js accessing the template if it's not exported? Does it look in the Inventory.js file if none was found in the main.js or?

Exporting the `Inventory` class allows any other module to use that class and all its methods.  The process of importing anything from `inventory.js` cause the module itself to get loaded so all the variables defined within `inventory.js` are active inside of `inventory.js`.  When you create an `Inventory` object via the exported class, you are running code in `inventory.js` that has access to all the data in that module.

Thing of import as two steps.  First load the module that is referenced (if it's not already loaded).  Then, fetch the exports that you requested imports for.

Comment: Neat, this cleared up all the confusion around this. Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: @MiloSx7 - I finished adding a few more answers to your detailed questions after you accepted the answer.  Just want to make sure you don't miss those.

Comment: I figured my question might be stupid after I posted it, I seem to understand core concepts pretty well, and I get stuck with the "simple" stuff... Yeah, I've just read that comment a couple more times now and everything is crystal clear. I also used to think that prototype functions inside a class create a unique function for each object instance...

Ever since I found out about ES6 the "I want to make a game" turned into "I want to learn and understand everything" overnight. It's kind of addicting

God bless you sir.